# Div Not Showing Up : Rollover Image Link

Tags: html, css, sprite

Live Example Page:

http://newsite.702wedding.com/cheap-las-vegas-weddings.asp

I want the 3rd box on the right side to have a sprite image link in it. I cant seem to get the darn thing to show up.

The Image is : reserve-a-date-right.jpg

its 801px wide, with 401px viewable.

Thanks as Always,
Any Ideas would be helpful.

What am I missing? I have spent 3 hours trying to figure this out.

Comment: 3rd box on the right? sorry, couldn't see such thing. Please post some relevant code and we'll try to spot where you went wrong.

Comment: Right Column, the Folder Looking Container just underneath the slideshow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add in: `display: block;` to `#package-right-box-promo a`

It should show up, though you may have to adjust the top margin. (Looks like `margin-top: 19px;` centers it nicely, but that's in Firefox 3)